# How can I define a method on a FactoryGirl factory?

Tags: ruby, factory-bot

How can I define a normal method for use in one of my FactoryGirl factories? For instance:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  def silly_horse_name
   verbs = %w[brunches dribbles haggles meddles]
   nouns = %w[landmines hamlets vandals piglets]
   "#{verbs.sample} with #{nouns.sample}".titleize
  end

  factory :racehorse do
    name { silly_horse_name } # eg, "Brunches with Landmines"

    after_build do |horse, evaluator|
      puts "oh boy, I built #{silly_horse_name}!"
    end

  end
end
```

Doing it this way does not call `silly_horse_name` at all; if it's redefined to `raise 'hey!'`, nothing happens.

I'm using FactoryGirl 2.5.2.

Answer (score 4):

The best solution I could find that didn't pollute the global namespace was to define it in a module. E.g.,

```
module FactoryHelpers
  extend self

  def silly_horse_name
    ...
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :racehorse do
    name { silly_horse_name }
  end
end
```

[Source](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/issues/564)

Comment: Do you have to include the `FactoryHelpers` module in the factory somehow? Using the above, I see `undefined method silly_horse_name for #<FactoryGirl::SyntaxRunner:0x007fd3b161cd30>`

Answer (score 2):

OK, here's my two cents (please note that there are subtle differences to Steve's answer):

```
# /spec/factory_helpers.rb:

module FactoryHelpers
  extend self

  def silly_penguin_name # who says penguins can't be silly too?!
    ...
  end
end
```

---

```
# /spec/factories.rb:

require 'factory_helpers'

FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :racepenguin do
    name { FactoryHelpers.silly_penguin_name }
  end

end
```

By the way, I am on FactoryGirl version 4.8.0 and Rails version 4.2.0.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to define that method on `main`.  So just move it to the top of your file outside of the `FactoryGirl.define` block.

Comment: That works. It's going into the global namespace, but it's only defined in the test environment, and if the name is unique enough, it may not matter.

Comment: I don't like this solution at all, but tried and couldn't find another solution.  What confuses me most about it is that [The FG documentation](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#callbacks) implies this is possible by using this example: `after(:build)  { |user| do_something_to(user) }`